# Add a row when conditions from multiple columns match in python?

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to add a row in a dataframe. The condition is when a user comes back (after 300 seconds) on the app again then I need to add a row. Below is my code. It works fine but takes a lot of execution time, as the real data frame has 10 million rows.

```
for i in range(1,len(df)):
    if df['user_id'][i]==df['user_id'][i-1] and (df['start_time'][i]-df['start_time'][i-1]).seconds>300:
        df.loc[len(df)]=[df['user_id'][i],df['start_time'][i],'psuedo_App_start_2']
```

Input:

```
user_id   start_time        event
100       03/04/19 6:11     psuedo_App_start
100       03/04/19 6:11     notification_receive
100       03/04/19 8:56     notification_dismiss
10        03/04/19 22:05    psuedo_App_start
10        03/04/19 22:05    subcategory_click
10        03/04/19 22:06    subcategory_click
```

output should look like:

```
user_id   start_time        event
100       03/04/19 6:11     psuedo_App_start
100       03/04/19 6:11     notification_receive
100       03/04/19 8:56     psuedo_App_start_2
100       03/04/19 8:56     notification_dismiss
10        03/04/19 22:05    psuedo_App_start
10        03/04/19 22:05    subcategory_click
10        03/04/19 22:06    subcategory_click
```

As seen in the output, there is a row added for user_id = 100, as he came back at 8.56 i.e after 300 seconds.

Comment: Do you have control over how these events are inserted into the dataframe?

Comment: no, other events are automatically generated

Comment: Why don't you do this: 1) remember what was the last timestamp you saw during full scan of the dataframe, 2) in the next scan only get the rows which have a higher timestamp (i.e. the new rows)

Comment: Can't really test it right now but you could `groupby['user_id','start_time']`, then use df.timedelta to check if the `start_time` for each id is bigger than 300 and insert a new line if condition is met (with the last `start_time` and `user_id` pulled from df)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First filter by 2 conditions - compare `user_id` by [`DataFrameGroupBy.shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.shift.html)ed values per groups, and also difference per groups by [`DataFrameGroupBy.diff`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.diff.html), then reassign `evet` column by [`DataFrame.assign`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html), last [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) together and sorting by [`DataFrame.sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html):

```
#MM/DD/YY HH:MM
#df['start_time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['start_time'])
#DD/MM/YY HH:MM
#df['start_time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['start_time'], dayfirst=True)

m1 = df['user_id'].eq(df.groupby('user_id')['user_id'].shift())
m2 = df.groupby('user_id')['start_time'].diff().dt.total_seconds() > 300

df1 = df[m1 & m2].assign(event='psuedo_App_start_2')

df1 = (pd.concat([df, df1], ignore_index=True)
         .sort_values(['user_id','start_time'], ascending=[False, True]))
print (df1)
   user_id          start_time                 event
0      100 2019-03-04 06:11:00      psuedo_App_start
1      100 2019-03-04 06:11:00  notification_receive
2      100 2019-03-04 08:56:00  notification_dismiss
6      100 2019-03-04 08:56:00    psuedo_App_start_2
3       10 2019-03-04 22:05:00      psuedo_App_start
4       10 2019-03-04 22:05:00     subcategory_click
5       10 2019-03-04 22:06:00     subcategory_click
```

Comment: can you help me understand what is stored in m1 and m2?

Comment: @nk23 There are boolean masks, first compared by `eq` for ==, second compared by >

Answer (score 0):

Usually in such cases you need to convert explicit cycles to vectorized operations. Try something like this:

```py
i = (df.user_id.values[1:] == df.user_id.values[:-1]) & ((df.start_time.values[1:] - df.start_time.values[:-1])/np.timedelta64(1, 's') > 300)
newRows = tt[np.append(False, i)].copy()
newRows.event = 'psuedo_App_start_2'
df.append(newRows)
```